# How to reference a common properties file from within an osgi bundle properties file?

Tags: apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

At the moment, I have a number of features/bundles that refer to a self named properties file. I want to create a number of common properties files, that are included in the individual bundle properties file.

I know that this doesn't work in core Java, but I'm sure I have read somewhere that you can include properties files in Karaf/OSGi/Blueprint, but now I want to do it, I can't find any reference on any of the sites I've been searching for.

What I can't find anywhere is the syntax for how to do it. Can anyone confirm *if* this is possible, and if so, what the syntax is to do this? Any pointers to suitable documentation would also be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at property placeholder? you can have a .cfg file in etc folder, and the properties can be referenced in blueprint file or the camel contexts, etc.

Comment: I can't modify the property placeholder because the blueprint is auto-generated. I seem to remember seeing somewhere a way to include one .cfg file from within another, but I now can't find this.

Comment: how are you generating your blueprint file? any references or examples?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using blueprint for your bundle:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.3.0"
           xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
             http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.3.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.3.0.xsd
             ">
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="my.shared" update-strategy="reload" >
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="SOURCE" value="DB" />
            <cm:property name="ENV" value="test" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
</blueprint>
```

For this, you can have a `my.shared.cfg` (look at the value of the attribute persistent-id in `cm:property-placeholder` tag) file in `${KARAF_HOME}/etc` directory.

my.shared.cfg file will have:

```
SOURCE=DB
ENV=test
```

Assuming that you would like to use this value to instantiate a bean using from the blueprint, you can do the following:

```xml
<bean id="myCustomBean" class="com.example.CustomBeanClass">
    <argument value="${SOURCE}" index="0" />
    <argument value="${ENV}" index="1" />
</bean>
```

You can refer [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2.1/html/deploying_into_apache_karaf/deploycamel-osgiconfigprops) for the information.

Let me know, if this does not help.

Regards,
Cooshal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cm:property-placeholder to get the property file value,
I have developed one simple example using blueprint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd     http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
<cm:property-placeholder
    persistent-id="org.usr.config" />
<camelContext id="log-example-context"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="log-route">
        <from id="_from1" uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1" />
        <log id="_log1" message="logging the property value::" />
        <log id="_log1" message="{{conf.data}}" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

`org.usr.config` should be placed in the $KARAF_HOME/etc/ as `org.usr.config.cfg`

The property can be like below

```
 conf.data=Chandra
```

You can refer my example [GIT](https://github.com/chandra-h-bitd/FuseTutorial/tree/master/RefPropertyCamel)

You can get more knowledge on [Apache community document](https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/properties.html)

I hope it helps,